# Create stored procedure which accepts input as stored procedure and produce results dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to implement this below requirements:

Sample procedure #1:

```
Procedure Proc1(Input1  VARCHAR2,
                Input2  NUMBER,
                Input3  VARCHAR2,
                Output  Sys_RefCursor)
IS
BEGIN
    ..................
    ..................
    ..................
END;
```

Sample procedure #2:

```
Procedure Proc2(Ipval1  VARCHAR2,
                Ipval2  NUMBER,
                Ipval3  VARCHAR3
                Output  Sys_RefCursor)
IS
Begin
..................
..................
..................
End;
```

Now the requirement is, I want to create a stored procedure which should accept the procedure name as input.

So according to the input procedure name, it should dynamically produce the result of it.

```
 Procedure GenProc(InputProcedureName   VARCHAR2,
                   InputListVal         VARCHAR2,
                   OutputCur            SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS

Begin
................Dynamic Code ............... To produce result set as per input procedurename
END;
```

Any idea how to write dynamic code to fulfill this requirement?

Let's say here:

- InputProcedureName -- Can be Proc1 or Proc2 ,
- InputListVal       -- List of input given in comma separated value for the input procedurenames,
- OutputCur          -- Should produce output list dynamically as per the input procedurename

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create a SP that takes an SP name and parameters as inputs and returns the result of the named SP?

Comment: OK, but - **why bother**? Isn't it way simpler to call either Proc1 or Proc2 and pass parameters directly to them and get the output also directly out of them?

Comment: @Littlefoot .. Yes but this is my scenario to work on.. i would be getting any proc name as input... not limited with just 2 of them..

Comment: @NickW ..Yes you are right.

Comment: I assumed it was a technical/homework exercise. @littlefoot I agree that this is pretty pointless in the real world

Comment: If you have *something* that will provide the input for that routing procedure, then this *something* can call it directly without additional procedure and parsing of argument list (because arguments can be structured, may have different positions in different procedures and this approach will lead to lots of bugs)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```sql
create or replace procedure Proc1 (
                par1 varchar2,
                par2 number,
                par3 varchar2,
                rc out sys_refcursor) is
begin 
    open rc for 
        select 'executing Proc1('||par1||','||par2||','||par3||')' result from dual;
end;
/
create or replace procedure execProc (
                procname varchar2,
                args sys.odciVarchar2List,
                rc out sys_refcursor) is
begin 
    execute immediate 'begin '||procname||q'[(:s1, :n2, :s3, :rc); end;]' 
        using args(1), to_number (args(2)), args(3), out rc;
end;
/
```

The execution and outcomes:

```
set autoprint on 
var rc refcursor
exec execProc ('Proc1', sys.odciVarchar2List ('abc', 123, 'def'), :rc)

RESULT
--------------------------------
executing Proc1(abc,123,def)
```

---

***Disclaimer:*** This answer is meant for educational purposes only!!!